# Delete folder in S3 using R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to delete all files in one folder.

I've tried

```
library(aws.s3)
delete_object(object = "folder_to_delete", bucket = "bucket_name/folder/sub_folder/")
delete_object(object = "bucket_name/folder/sub_folder/folder_to_delete")
```

R returns

```
[1] TRUE
```

But finally, nothing is deleted.
If nobody knows how to do this, maybe someone knows how to list all the file names which are stored in a specific folder (`aws.s3` library offers the only function for listing all names of buckets, not files)

To be more precise, I don't know specific names of files inside the folder to delete.

They have only in common initial part - "report". It means inside folder "folder_to_delete"
We have files like:

```
report_1234
report_87688
report_uyrtt
```

Comment: Did your try `unlink`?

Comment: But ```unlink``` works only in personal environment, right?

Comment: I think you're right. I never tried it outside my local.

Comment: I am not familiar with `aws.s3`, so this might not work for you.
Have you tried to make a list of the files in the folder, and then passing that to `delete_object()`?

For example `list_of_files <- list.files("folder_to_delete")` and then
 `delete_object(list_of_files)`

Comment: Okay, I have found argument "prefix" in function ```all_files <- get_bucket(max = Inf, bucket = "bucket_name",  prefix = "folder/sub_folder/folder_to_delete") ``` which indicate correct path to the folder. And then you can paste all names in a loop with ```delete_file()```. Function ```list.files()``` works only in your environment, not on connection with s3, but thanks for your time:)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, with the added benefit of having all the versatility of the tidyverse to pick which files you need... or don't.

```
library(aws.s3)
library(tidyverse)

# Bucket contents in dataframe
bucket <- 
  get_bucket_df("bucket_name", 
                prefix = "folder/subfolder/folder_with_contents_to_delete/")

# List of files to delete
files_to_delete <-
  bucket %>% 
# Filter based on deletion criteria
  # Keeping files modified after 01 April 2020
  filter(LastModified >= "2020-04-01") %>% 
  # Keep file names
  select(Key) %>% 
  pull() 

# Loop through file list
for(file in files_to_delete){
  delete_object(file, 
                "bucket_name", 
                prefix = "folder/subfolder/folder_with_contents_to_delete/")
}
```

I also tried passing the `files_to_delete` as a list to `delete_object` but it wouldn't take a list.

```
delete_object(file, 
              "bucket_name", 
              prefix = "folder/subfolder/folder_with_contents_to_delete/")
```